# ASP.NET Losing session after page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

i'm testing my asp.net web project with visual studio 2015.
I have a login page and then an home page for the authenticated user. The home page uses several data loaded in session without any problem.
But as soon as the page load is complete the Session End event is fired and i lose all the session data.

Do you know why does this happen? It's not a session time-out because i've set it to 20 minutes.

Comment: "When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem." http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I get this problem. My office pc is a dumb terminal. I log in to the development box with terminal server client. 

From the development box I open the asp.net project, on a network share. The deployed project works without errors on iis. If I open the project in VS, I get errors at runtime. The main error is that sessions will end after the page loads. The temporary fix is to reboot the development box. 

If I check out the project and use a local copy on the development box then all the errors disappear. So I now copy the project from the network share to a drive on the dev box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the web.config file changing for any reason? This can cause the application pool to restart.

Comment: I checked that, but the last edit data of my Web-config file is 2016-08-30